# Linux Authentication by Active Directory without joining to domain

Tags: linux, active-directory, domain, windows-authentication, boot

I have a Win 2008 AD based network. I want to setup a few boxes with dual boot Win/Linux. How can I achieve to authenticate the users with existing AD in Linux?

All solutions - I have found yet - join the linux boxes to the domain. I think, this is a problem in case of dual boot and the same netbios name of the client. Are there possibilities without joining to domain?

The home dir should be on a nfs4 server (linux), so I need kerberos.

Which solutions are possible, which are most stable?

Thanks for any advice!

Sepp Hofbauer

Comment: It's not the NetBIOS name that's a problem-- it's that you, practically, can't allow both OS's to share the same computer account. (I suppose you *could* if you prevented the Windows machine from rotating the workstation trust password...)  Why not just use a different computer name for the Linux OS?

Comment: I have an image cloning and deployment solution which is setting the hostname automatically from dns entries. I think to change this system is more complicated than making auth without domain membership.

Comment: Could you not just adjust you imaging system to append an L or something to the hostname when applying the image?  Or have a script in the os image that makes the change before it joins the domain?

Answer (score 1):

You can make local accounts in Linux for the users but authenticate from kerberos.  When users login to Linux they will get a kerberos ticket from AD.  No need to join the domain.

Comment: It's a school with ca. 1000 users which often change. I wanted to avoid create local users. Is there a solution for auto creation?

Comment: In that case you could get account details from ldap and authenticate from kerberos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AD authentication using just LDAP without Kerberos. See here: http://htfdidt.blogspot.ca/2014_06_01_archive.html